# How long can be the maximum size for RegistryValueKind.String?

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to write a string value that could be very long (about 100k)

```
string key = @"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\my-key-name";
string valueName = "my-value-name";
string value = "a-very-long-string ..."; // this could be about 100,000 chars

Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(key,valueName, value,
   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
```

I have not found any documentations on the value size by searching google and ..
How can i make sure that this will work on most operating systems such as Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows Server 2003 and so on.
any advice is appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't belong in the registry, use a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724872(v=vs.85).aspx):

- Key name: 255 characters.
- Value name: 16,383 characters
- Value: Available memory (latest format) / 1 MB (standard format)

So as long as you keep it below 1 MB it seems you should be good. The page does seem kinda old though, so I would guess that the 1 MB limit is for Windows 9x and older. Just a guess though..!

Edit: And yes, as Hans just commented. Bad idea, that's not what the registry is for...